# how to copy a collection from one from another in robomongo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a collection named dashboard in one db and i want to copy that collection to another db using robomongo. How can i do this? I tried creating a new collection in 2nd db and tried copying but it failed. so somebody please help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another db - another connection. But Robomongo works only with one connection in one period of time. That is why it is impossible.

I suggest you to use mongoimport/mongoexoprt tools for your task. They comes with mongo, are located in same folder as mongod.exe and allows to move collections via databases, by exporting to and importing from a `json` file.

Code sample:

```
mongoexport --db testFrom --port portFrom --username userFrom --password passwordFrom --collection yourCollection --out test.json
mongoimport --db testTo --port portTo --username userTo --password passwordTo --collection yourCollection --file test.json
```

Comment: No i trying in different port. the first one runs in port 3001 and other one in port 3003..so how can i copy a collection from port 3001 to port 3003

Comment: It is not possible you uses 2 different connection(Different port also means that connection is different). Robomongo could not execute queries to 2 different connections in a same time.

Comment: I modifyied the answer to show how to copy a collection between to servers.